# Excel VBA macro - find the cell location from which cells in two columns match the row and column in another workbook then paste a value

Tags: excel, vba, location, conditional-statements, matching

So in column A and column B there are two sets of values from workbook 1 that should match with the position in workbook 2.

```
    **WORKBOOK 1**
    column A        column B         column C

    a               1                32
    b               2                45
    f               6                12
    g               9                55
    e               5                99
```

On this diagram, X marks location where the cells from workbook 1 match the position in workbook 2. The columns represent column A and the rows represent column B. Once the location has been found the corresponding value in column C will be pasted into the location.

```
**WORKBOOK 2**
   1 2 5 9 6
   _ _ _ _ _
a |X
b |  X
f |        X
g |      X   
e |    X
```

**FYI - the rows and columns in this example are from workbook 1, not the default column and row numbers.**

My attempt, but what would you use instead of putting "B2" for the location?

```
Sub Location()
Dim i as Long, k as Long, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Set ws1 = Workbooks("A").Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("B").Worksheets("Sheet 2")

For i = 1 to 5
variable = ws1.Cells(i, 1) && ws1.Cells(i, 2)
   For k = 1 to 5
   If ws2.Cells(i, 1) && ws2.Cell(1, i) = variable Then
      ws1.Range("C1").Copy 
      ws2.Range("B2").Paste
   End if 
   Next k
Next I

End Sub
```

**Desired output**

```
   1 2 5 9 6
   _ _ _ _ _
a |32
b |  45
f |        12
g |      55   
e |    99
```

Any suggestions on how to begin this? Also I know the vlookup function exists but using VBA code would this be achievable?

**Errors:**

[image: Errors]

And this is the input, column B in this image is acting as column C in the example.

[image: input]

**Input code:**

```
Sub Location()
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Copy of Retrofit Monthly Invoicing 2017.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Book4").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For k = 2 To ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws2.Cells(i, k).Value = ws2.Evaluate("IFERROR(INDEX(" & ws1.Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(" & ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ")" & _
            "/((" & ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & " = " & ws2.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0) & ")*(" & ws1.Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & "=" & _
            ws2.Cells(1, k).Address(0, 0) & ")),1)),"""")")
        Next k
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, I included my attempt now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not adverse to formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5)/((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5 = $A2)*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5=B$1)),1)),"")
```

In the first cell, then copy and drag over and down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Then just use Evaluate and the formula:

```
Sub Location()
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For k = 2 To ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws2.Cells(i, k).Value = ws2.Evaluate("IFERROR(INDEX(" & ws1.Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(" & ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ")" & _
            "/((" & ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & " = " & ws2.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0) & ")*(" & ws1.Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & "=" & _
            ws2.Cells(1, k).Address(0, 0) & ")),1)),"""")")
        Next k
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a VBA version to do this rather than formula based?

Comment: Also the example is a simplified version as the X location could be anywhere within the worksheet 2, because the rows and columns are ordered the same as worksheet 1 columns but it can be different

Comment: @F.Lee this formula does not matter the pattern.  See edit

Comment: @BruceWayne  I see now but I think for my case a VBA version would be more useful for the case of applying a macro to multiple files

Comment: So I have been using the VBA code on some more excel files and for some reason if I have a file that contains a lot of rows and columns in worksheet 2 that should remain empty after running the macro I get #VALUE! errors appear in every single cell in the specified rows and columns. Any ideas on solution?

Comment: I will add a screenshot of the errors in the opening paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Do you need VBA? You can do this with an Array formula.

I'm using Sheets, but just have both workbooks open and use that, to fix the references:

Data is like this on Sheet1:

[image]

Then, in your Sheet2 (or other workbook, etc), place this in `A1`, and enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5,MATCH(ROW()&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",""),Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5&Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,0)),"")
```

Drag over and down:

[image]

Comment: I think you mistook my columns because I think you are using the default row and columns, whereas my columns in workbook 1 could be any value.